# Proving that $E(MS_{Trt})=\sigma+n\sigma^2_T$ for the Random Effects Model

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

[image]

This was in my textbook, but I can't make heads or tails of it. Honestly, I think that there might be a typo. Any help making sense of this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to add a few more details, like what is the distribution of the terms $\tau_i$ and $\epsilon_{ij}$, the excerpt suggests they are also independent, and $\mu$ is deterministic or random? And $N = a \cdot n$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have $a$ random batches, with $n$ random samples from each batch.
Final products are made from the $an$ samples and we want to study the
variability of the final product.

Much as supposed in the Comment by @Nadiels, the excerpt uses $N = an.$ The
model is

$$Y_{ij} = \mu + \tau_i + \epsilon_{ij},$$
where the 'grand mean' $\mu$ is an unknown constant, 
$\tau_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(0, \sigma_\tau),$ and
$\epsilon_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(0, \sigma).$

After cancelling the constants $\pm an\mu^2,$ the equation of interest can be rewritten as
$$(a-1)E(\text{MST}) = (an\sigma_\tau^2 - n\sigma_\tau^2) + (a\sigma^2 - \sigma^2)
= n(a-1)\sigma_\tau^2 + (a-1)\sigma^2$$
or $E(\text{MST}) = n\sigma_\tau^2 + \sigma^2,$ as claimed.

---

*Notes on estimation of parameters.*
The grand mean can be estimated by $\hat \mu = \bar Y = \frac{1}{an}\sum_i \sum_j Y_{ij},$
and the error variance by $\hat \sigma = E(\text{MSE}).$ Both estimators are
method of moments' estimators. Confidence
intervals for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ can be based on $\frac{\bar Y - \mu}{\sqrt{\text{MSE}/an}} \sim \mathsf{T}(an-1)$ and 
$(an -1)\text{MSE}/\sigma^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(a(n-1)),$
respectively.

However, there is no truly satisfactory method of moments estimator of $\sigma_\tau^2.$
An unbiased estimator is 
$\hat \sigma_\tau^2 = (\text{MST} - \text{MSE})/n,$ which comes directly
from the equation you asked about. However, because of the
subtraction, this estimator can be negative, especially if the batch
variance $\sigma_\tau^2$ is quite small relative to $\sigma^2.$
Of course, it is problematic to get a negative estimate of a parameter known to be positive. The distribution of $\hat \sigma_\tau^2$ is not obvious. Efforts
to get an approximate chi-squared distribution have had mixed results.

The maximum likelihood estimator of $\hat \sigma_\tau$ can be found
by numerical methods, which can also sometimes be used to get a satisfactory
confidence interval (depending on the computational stability of the
estimator). A Bayesian interval estimates for $\hat \sigma_\tau$ can also be found, often using Gibbs Sampling (a Markov Chain Monte Carlo computational method).

Comment: I was mainly confused about squaring and taking the expectations. Like for example, the textbook says that $\epsilon^2_{i.}$ should be replaced by $n\sigma^2$, but I don't see any $\epsilon^2_{i.}$ in the expression.

Comment: There will be $E(e_{ij})^2$ when you take the square. Because $E(e_{ij}) = 0.,$ you have $E(e_{ij})^2 = \sigma^2.$ How is $e_{i.}$ related to $e_{ij}?$ Write it out. There is a lot of algebra to get from the expression above the black bar to the expression below. However, the result $n\sigma_\tau^2 + \sigma^2$ is correct.